# How to fix connection of postgresql after move data directory from the root HD to another HDD?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, permissions, database-connection

I'm work with postgresql over large datasets and I move my database from the same HDD were is Ubuntu 18.04 installed to a other HDD.

I did the same process and move the data_directory to "Home" (which is at same HDD of the Ubuntu, but in other partition), in this location the postgresql works fine. The problem is I need a big space to upload my data (like 2 TB HDD) because that I try to move to another HDD, empty and formmated exclusive for the DB.

I follow to this tutorial [Link of change Data Folder](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04). Using the follow commands in Ubuntu terminal:

```
 su postgres

 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /media/path/postgresql/10/main -l logfile start

 sudo systemctl stop postgresql

 sudo systemctl status postgresql

 sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /media/path/postgresql

 sudo mv /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/lib/postgresql/10/main.bak

 sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf  (change "data_directory")

 sudo systemctl start postgresql

 sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

In addition, I pass to the postgres the ownership of the folder as

```
  chown -R postgres:postgres /media/path/postgresql/10/main
```

I write the modifications in "/path/postgresql.conf" to adjust to new data directory, reestart the server and I can't connect to server.

At terminal I get this message if I try to connect

```
 "could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?"
```

At Pgadmin client I get the problem is manifested as no connection.

[image: pgadmin client]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **rsync** did not copied several files for some reason. May be they were not ready yet after the server stopped or something else.

After I made it once more next day, it started well:

> sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/10/main.bak/ /media/disk1/postgres/postgresql/10/main/

Also try to check log for the actual reason:

> tail -n 100 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log

At my case it was

> postgres: could not find the database system
>   Expected to find it in the directory "/media/disk1/postgres/postgresql/10/main",
>   but could not open file "/media/disk1/postgres/postgresql/10/main/global/pg_control": No such file or directory
>   pg_ctl: could not start server
>   Examine the log output.